# How do I get private IP address of VM in nested ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have a nested template which creates VM which works fine but I need to return private IP address of that machine to main template and as `output`. I create following output in my nested template but it fails with error message

`Deployment template validation failed: 'The template reference 'swarmmanager1NetworkInterface' is not valid: could not find template resource or resource copy with this name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.'.`

Here is entire template

```html
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_A1",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Size of VMs in the VM Scale Set."
      }
    },
    "windowsOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers",
      "allowedValues": [
        "2008-R2-SP1",
        "2012-Datacenter",
        "2012-R2-Datacenter",
        "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Windows version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Windows version. Allowed values: 2008-R2-SP1, 2012-Datacenter, 2012-R2-Datacenter."
      }
    },
    "registrationKey": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Registration key to use to onboard to the Azure Automation DSC pull/reporting server"
      }
    },
    "registrationUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Registration url of the Azure Automation DSC pull/reporting server"
      }
    },
    "DSCExtensionTagVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Change this to redeploy DSC"
      }
    },
    "nodeConfigurationName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "MyService.webServer",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the node configuration, on the Azure Automation DSC pull server, that this node will be configured as"
      }
    },
    "configurationMode": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ApplyAndAutoCorrect",
      "allowedValues": [
        "ApplyOnly",
        "ApplyAndMonitor",
        "ApplyAndAutoCorrect"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "DSC agent (LCM) configuration mode setting. ApplyOnly, ApplyAndMonitor, or ApplyAndAutoCorrect"
      }
    },
    "configurationModeFrequencyMins": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 15,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "DSC agent (LCM) configuration mode frequency setting, in minutes"
      }
    },
    "refreshFrequencyMins": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 30,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "DSC agent (LCM) refresh frequency setting, in minutes"
      }
    },
    "rebootNodeIfNeeded": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": true,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "DSC agent (LCM) rebootNodeIfNeeded setting"
      }
    },
    "actionAfterReboot": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ContinueConfiguration",
      "allowedValues": [
        "ContinueConfiguration",
        "StopConfiguration"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "DSC agent (LCM) actionAfterReboot setting. ContinueConfiguration or StopConfiguration"
      }
    },
    "allowModuleOverwrite": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "DSC agent (LCM) allowModuleOverwrite setting"
      }
    },
    "automationAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myAutomationAccount",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Automation account to use.  Check the SKU and tags to make sure they match the existing account."
      }
    },
    "automationRegionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "East US 2",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Japan East",
        "East US 2",
        "West Europe",
        "Southeast Asia",
        "South Central US",
        "Central India"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The region the Automation account is located in."
      }
    },
    "vmssName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "String used as a base for naming resources. Must be 3-57 characters in length and globally unique across Azure. A hash is prepended to this string for some resources, and resource-specific information is appended."
      },
      "maxLength": 57
    },
    "instanceCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Number of VM instances (100 or less)."
      },
      "maxValue": 100
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Admin username on all VMs."
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Admin password on all VMs."
      }
    },
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Auto-generated container in staging storage account to receive post-build staging folder upload"
      }
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Auto-generated token to access _artifactsLocation"
      }
    },
    "dockerswarmstorageaccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ]
    },
    "swarmmanager1Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "defaultValue": "swarmmanager1"
    },
    "swarmmanagerpublicIPDnsName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[uniqueString(subscription().subscriptionId)]",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "namingInfix": "[toLower(substring(concat(parameters('vmssName'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)), 0, 9))]",
    "longNamingInfix": "[toLower(parameters('vmssName'))]",
    "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "subnetPrefix": "10.0.8.0/21",
    "virtualNetworkName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'vnet')]",
    "natPoolName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'natpool')]",
    "publicIPAddressName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'pip')]",
    "subnetName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'subnet')]",
    "nicName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'nic')]",
    "ipConfigName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'ipconfig')]",
    "imageReference": {
      "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
      "offer": "WindowsServer",
      "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
      "version": "latest"
    },
    "virtualNetworkID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "appGwPublicIPAddressName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'appGwPip')]",
    "bePoolName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'bepool')]",
    "frontEndIPConfigID": "[concat(variables('lbID'),'/frontendIPConfigurations/loadBalancerFrontEnd')]",
    "appGwName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'appGw')]",
    "loadBalancerName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'lb')]",
    "publicIPAddressID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
    "lbID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers',variables('loadBalancerName'))]",
    "appGwPublicIPAddressID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('appGwPublicIPAddressName'))]",
    "appGwID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways',variables('appGwName'))]",
    "appGwSubnetName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'),'appGwSubnet')]",
    "appGwSubnetPrefix": "10.0.1.0/24",
    "appGwSubnetID": "[concat(variables('virtualNetworkID'),'/subnets/',variables('appGwSubnetName'))]",
    "appGwFrontendPort": 80,
    "appGwBackendPort": 80,
    "appGwBePoolName": "[concat(variables('namingInfix'), 'appGwBepool')]",
    "computeApiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
    "networkApiVersion": "2016-03-30",
    "natStartPort": 50000,
    "natEndPort": 50119,
    "natBackendPort": 3389,
    "DSCArchiveFolder": "DSC",
    "DSCArchiveFileName": "DSC.zip",
    "dockerswarmstorageaccountName": "[concat('sa', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "swarmmanager1ImagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "swarmmanager1ImageOffer": "WindowsServer",
    "swarmmanager1OSDiskName": "swarmmanager1OSDisk",
    "swarmmanager1VmSize": "Standard_D2_v2",
    "swarmmanager1VnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "swarmmanager1SubnetRef": "[concat(variables('swarmmanager1VnetID'), '/subnets/', variables('subnetName'))]",
    "swarmmanager1StorageAccountContainerName": "vhds",
    "swarmmanager1NicName": "[concat(parameters('swarmmanager1Name'), 'NetworkInterface')]",
    "swarmmanagerpublicIPName": "swarmmanagerpublicIP",
    "swarmmanagerdeploymentTemplateFolder": "nestedtemplates",
    "swarmmanagerdeploymentTemplateFileName": "swarmmanagerdeployment.json",
    "swarmmanagerdeploymentTemplateParametersFileName": "swarmmanagerdeployment.parameters.json"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[variables('appGwSubnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[variables('appGwSubnetPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
      "name": "[variables('loadBalancerName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
            "properties": {
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[variables('publicIPAddressID')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('bePoolName')]"
          }
        ],
        "inboundNatPools": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('natPoolName')]",
            "properties": {
              "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
              },
              "protocol": "tcp",
              "frontendPortRangeStart": "[variables('natStartPort')]",
              "frontendPortRangeEnd": "[variables('natEndPort')]",
              "backendPort": "[variables('natBackendPort')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('appGwPublicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",

        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "appgwvip"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",

        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "rdpvip"
        }
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
      "name": "[variables('appGwName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('networkApiVersion')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('appGwPublicIPAddressName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard_Small",
          "tier": "Standard",
          "capacity": "1"
        },
        "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGwIpConfig",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('appGwSubnetID')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "appGwFrontendIP",
            "properties": {
              "PublicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[variables('appGwPublicIPAddressID')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "frontendPorts": [
          {
            "name": "appGwFrontendPort",
            "properties": {
              "Port": "[variables('appGwFrontendPort')]"
            }
          }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('appGwBePoolName')]"
          }
        ],
        "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
          {
            "name": "appGwBackendHttpSettings",
            "properties": {
              "Port": "[variables('appGwBackendPort')]",
              "Protocol": "Http",
              "CookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled"
            }
          }
        ],
        "httpListeners": [
          {
            "name": "appGwHttpListener",
            "properties": {
              "FrontendIPConfiguration": {
                "Id": "[concat(variables('appGwID'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/appGwFrontendIP')]"
              },
              "FrontendPort": {
                "Id": "[concat(variables('appGwID'), '/frontendPorts/appGwFrontendPort')]"
              },
              "Protocol": "Http",
              "SslCertificate": null
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestRoutingRules": [
          {
            "Name": "rule1",
            "properties": {
              "RuleType": "Basic",
              "httpListener": {
                "id": "[concat(variables('appGwID'), '/httpListeners/appGwHttpListener')]"
              },
              "backendAddressPool": {
                "id": "[concat(variables('appGwID'), '/backendAddressPools/', variables('appGwBePoolName'))]"
              },
              "backendHttpSettings": {
                "id": "[concat(variables('appGwID'), '/backendHttpSettingsCollection/appGwBackendHttpSettings')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
      "name": "[variables('namingInfix')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('computeApiVersion')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/', variables('appGwName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'))]"
      ],
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('vmSku')]",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "capacity": "[parameters('instanceCount')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "overprovision": "false",
        "singlePlacementGroup": "true",
        "upgradePolicy": {
          "mode": "Automatic"
        },
        "virtualMachineProfile": {
          "storageProfile": {
            "osDisk": {
              "caching": "ReadWrite",
              "createOption": "FromImage"
            },
            "dataDisks": [],
            "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]"
          },
          "osProfile": {
            "computerNamePrefix": "[variables('namingInfix')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
          },
          "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaceConfigurations": [
              {
                "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
                "properties": {
                  "primary": "true",
                  "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                      "name": "[variables('ipConfigName')]",
                      "properties": {
                        "subnet": {
                          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'), '/subnets/', variables('subnetName'))]"
                        },
                        "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                          {
                            "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'), '/backendAddressPools/', variables('bePoolName'))]"
                          }
                        ],
                        "loadBalancerInboundNatPools": [
                          {
                            "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', variables('loadBalancerName'), '/inboundNatPools/', variables('natPoolName'))]"
                          }
                        ],
                        "ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": [
                          {
                            "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/', variables('appGwName'), '/backendAddressPools/', variables('appGwBePoolName'))]"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "extensionProfile": {
            "extensions": [
              {
                "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
                "properties": {
                  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                  "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
                  "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('DSCExtensionTagVersion')]",
                  "settings": {
                    "configuration": {
                      "url": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('DSCArchiveFolder'), '/', variables('DSCArchiveFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
                      "script": "DSC.ps1",
                      "function": "Main"
                    },
                    "configurationArguments": {
                      "RegistrationKey": "[parameters('registrationKey')]",
                      "RegistrationUrl": "[parameters('registrationUrl')]",
                      "NodeConfigurationName": "[parameters('nodeConfigurationName')]",
                      "ConfigurationMode": "[parameters('configurationMode')]",
                      "ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins": "[parameters('configurationModeFrequencyMins')]",
                      "RefreshFrequencyMins": "[parameters('refreshFrequencyMins')]",
                      "RebootNodeIfNeeded": "[parameters('rebootNodeIfNeeded')]",
                      "ActionAfterReboot": "[parameters('actionAfterReboot')]",
                      "AllowModuleOverwrite": "[parameters('allowModuleOverwrite')]"
                    }
                  },
                  "type": "DSC",
                  "typeHandlerVersion": "2.26"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "swarmmanager",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "name": "[parameters('swarmmanager1Name')]",
              "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('dockerswarmstorageaccountName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('swarmmanager1NicName'))]"
              ],
              "tags": {
                "displayName": "swarmmanager1"
              },
              "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                  "vmSize": "[variables('swarmmanager1VmSize')]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                  "computerName": "[parameters('swarmmanager1Name')]",
                  "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                  "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                  "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "[variables('swarmmanager1ImagePublisher')]",
                    "offer": "[variables('swarmmanager1ImageOffer')]",
                    "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
                    "version": "latest"
                  },
                  "osDisk": {
                    "name": "swarmmanager1OSDisk",
                    "vhd": {
                      "uri": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('dockerswarmstorageaccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob, variables('swarmmanager1StorageAccountContainerName'), '/', variables('swarmmanager1OSDiskName'), '.vhd')]"
                    },
                    "caching": "ReadWrite",
                    "createOption": "FromImage"
                  }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                  "networkInterfaces": [
                    {
                      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('swarmmanager1NicName'))]"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "[variables('dockerswarmstorageaccountName')]",
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
              "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('dockerswarmstorageaccountType')]"
              },
              "dependsOn": [],
              "tags": {
                "displayName": "dockerswarmstorageaccount"
              },
              "kind": "Storage"
            },
            {
              "name": "[variables('swarmmanager1NicName')]",
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
              "tags": {
                "displayName": "swarmmanager1Nic"
              },
              "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                  {
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                      "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                      "subnet": {
                        "id": "[variables('swarmmanager1SubnetRef')]"
                      },
                      "publicIPAddress": {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('swarmmanagerpublicIPName'))]"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "[variables('swarmmanagerpublicIPName')]",
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
              "dependsOn": [],
              "tags": {
                "displayName": "swarmmanagerpublicIP"
              },
              "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                "dnsSettings": {
                  "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('swarmmanagerpublicIPDnsName')]"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "outputs": {
                "returnedIPAddress": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "value": "[reference(variables('swarmmanager1NicName')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Comment: show child template

Comment: Could you share your template?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Your output snippet and your "entire template" have different references in them - which on returns the error?  (the first isn't defined in your template)

Comment: Changed question to only show entire template and error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a couple things - you have your output in the nested template in the resources array - outputs should be a peer of the resources array.  That's not getting flagged because of the inline reference() call fails before this.

First, reference() calls are often made very early in the deployment - sometimes earlier than you want them to be. When the resource being referenced is defined in the same template, it works as expected.  When it's not defined in the same template, the GET happens immediately and the resource may not exist.  That's a nuance of the reference() function that's a little tangential but important to know as you use it...

Combine that behavior with the inline template deployment.  Inline deployments have a number of design quirks that make them pretty hard to use for anything "advanced".  You won't be able to do what you're doing with an inline deployment.  If you use a templateLink (i.e. another file), you can deploy the nic and output the ipconfig in the same template.

That help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Problem with linked template I have to pass parameters one by one by master deployment file and define those in linked template as well, which super tedious with big number of parameters

Comment: Agree this is not the most efficient way to code it... not sure if it helps but you can also link to a param file - template of course needs to have everything defined, but depending on your workflow, passing them might be easier that way...

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, we were deploying using Azure Pipelines, the approach i took was 1) Deploy Template and pass the RG name and VMSS name as template outputs 2) ARM Outputs - Use this snippet to publish the above results as vars to use downstream 3) Azure Powershell to get the IPs of all VMSS instances and publish them as pipeline variables 4) Write the pipeline vars file to a blob. Hope this helps

```
$iplist=@()
$i=1
$nicinfo=Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroupName) - 
VirtualMachineScaleSetName $(VmssName)
foreach($nic in $nicinfo){
$iplist += $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
 } 
foreach($ip in $iplist){
 Write-host Private ip $i is $ip
 Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Privateip$i;]$ip"
 $i++
}
```